# Using require VS if / revert custom Error

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

When checking effects on a Solidity function, are there any benefits or trade-offs using `require` VS using `if (!condition) revert CustomError()`, or is it just a matter of preference?

I'm thinking gas consumption, logging, etc...